# Jwt list of audience in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt, jose4j

When creating the token, I've set a list of audience as follows:

```
JwtClaims claims = new JwtClaims();
        claims.setIssuer(issuer);
        claims.setAudience(Lists.newArrayList(audiences));
        claims.setExpirationTimeMinutesInTheFuture(60);
        claims.setJwtId(keyId);
        claims.setIssuedAtToNow(); 
        claims.setNotBeforeMinutesInThePast(2);
        claims.setSubject(subject);
```

The problem comes on the consumer side that is not giving me the expected audience.
This is what I've done on the consumer side:

```
JwtConsumer jwtConsumer = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
                .setRequireExpirationTime()
                .setAllowedClockSkewInSeconds(30)
                .setRequireSubject()
                .setExpectedIssuer(issuer)
                .setExpectedAudience(String.valueOf(Lists.newArrayList(audiences)))
                .setVerificationKey(rsaJsonWebKey.getKey())
                .build();
```

There's something wrong with the setExpectedAudience but I can't find the problem. This is what I got in the console.

```
Invalid JWT! org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.InvalidJwtException: JWT (claims->{"iss":"EXAMPLEISSUER","aud":["test1","test2","test3"],"exp":1657880599,"jti":"EXAMPLE_SHA1withRSA","iat":1657876999,"nbf":1657876879,"sub":"example"}) rejected due to invalid claims or other invalid content. Additional details: [[8] Audience (aud) claim [test1, test2, test3] doesn't contain an acceptable identifier. Expected [test1, test2, test3] as an aud value.]
```

Comment: Your IDE should help you with this. You are using `setExpectedAudience` wrong: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.bitbucket.b_c/jose4j/0.5.1/org/jose4j/jwt/consumer/JwtConsumerBuilder.html#setExpectedAudience(boolean,%20java.lang.String...)

Comment: I've tried this also but nothing. .setExpectedAudience(false, String.valueOf(audiences))

Comment: The second parameter is an array, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

`setExpectedAudience()` accepts varargs, so make an ordinary `String[]` array
from your `audiences` and use it as an argument.

Comment: I've declare my audiences as a @Value("#{'${example.audience}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> audiences;

Comment: What worked for me was this: .setExpectedAudience(true, audiences.toArray(new String[]{})) but I don't know if it's right

Comment: .. which is exactly what you can see in my answer